# Concatenate number varible to number on input field using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an imput field that has a numeric value but I want to concatenate a number to it using JQuery.

This is the input field code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <label for="name"> Código Postal:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CodigoPostal" name="txtCodigoPostal" value="2" readonly>
</div>
```

this is how I tried to concatenate the variable to the input field value:

```
var IdCanton = 0701;

$('#CodigoPostal').val($('#CodigoPostal').val().join(IdCanton));
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below?

To concatenate string, the `+` sign is used...

```js
var IdCanton = "0701"; // Has to be a string here... If you need to keep the leading zero

$('#CodigoPostal').val($('#CodigoPostal').val()+IdCanton);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <label for="name"> Código Postal:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CodigoPostal" name="txtCodigoPostal" value="2" readonly>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To concatenate just use `+` sign.

```
$('#CodigoPostal').val($('#CodigoPostal').val() + IdCanton);
```

If `$('#CodigoPostal').val()` result will be type Number use `toString()` like that:

```
$('#CodigoPostal').val($('#CodigoPostal').val().toString() + IdCanton);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two numbers then using `+` will add them rather than concat, eg:

```js
console.log(20 + 19);
```

if you want to concatenate them, then you need to convert them to a string, which you can do by adding `""`, eg:

```js
console.log("" + 20 + 19);
```